# Flutter Provider The ‘onScaleUpdate’ in ‘GestureDetector’ can’t trigger ‘rebuild’ continuously?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

In the code below, only one 'build' will be print every time multiple 'details' are print. I want it  to print one 'build' every time it print one'details'. What should I do?

In the code below, only one 'build' will be print every time multiple 'details' are print. I want it  to print one 'build' every time it print one'details'. What should I do?

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyApp();
  }
}

class _MyApp extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Material(
        child: FlutterTest(),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class FlutterTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FlutterTestState createState() => _FlutterTestState();
}

class _FlutterTestState extends State<FlutterTest> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => Controller(),
      child: Demo(),
    );
  }
}

class Controller extends ChangeNotifier {
  int count = 0;
  void countIncrement() {
    count++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoState createState() => _DemoState();
}

class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("build");
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        child: Text(context.watch<Controller>().count.toString()),
      ),
      onScaleUpdate: (details) {
        print("details");
        context.read<Controller>().countIncrement();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/33950845/111184336-d60e4400-85eb-11eb-875f-db0a7253e7cf.png